# WP inset post not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to migrate content from `typo3` database to `wordpress` ,I have 274 records in database but when exiting this script i get 25 records only inserted.
Any help is appreciated.

```
$result = mysql_query($query,$link);

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object($result) ) {

      $post_id = wp_insert_post(
            array(
                'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
                'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
                'post_author'       =>  1,
                'post_name'     =>  sanitize_title($row->title),
                'post_title'        =>  $row->title,
                'post_status'       =>  'publish',
                'post_type'     =>  'post',
            ));
        }
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Cannot see any error in your post. post what error you are getting

Comment: error is "Could not insert post in the database"

Comment: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.3.1/wp-includes/post.php#L3444  for some rows 'post_title'        =>  $row->title,  this value may be making issues

Comment: actually i updated the code to use esc_attr($row->title) to escape title but it return empty string. so i think the problem is related to UTF-8 encoding

Comment: most probably thats the case

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your script is timing out or insert operations are slow. Do you can provide more information, any errors, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

i resolve the problem  by adding **mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");** after mysql_connect statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query($query,$link);

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object($result) ) {

      $post_id = wp_insert_post(
            array(
                'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
                'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
                'post_author'       =>  1,
                'post_name'     =>  sanitize_title($row->title),
                'post_title'        =>  utf8_encode ($row->title),
                'post_status'       =>  'publish',
                'post_type'     =>  'post',
            ));
        }
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Please ckeck that your post title is ok by print it first or you can echo;

```
    echo sanitize_title($row->title);
```